# Tomcat: No such file or directory

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, fileupload

После того как я добавил в свой application.properties строку:

> upload_path=/home/deploy/my-app/uploads

Я столкнулся с тем, что приложение стало выбрасывать эту ошибку при попытке загрузки файла:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/tomcat.17108009837752391379.5000/work/Tomcat/localhost/ROOT/upload_186625aa_b4dc_4be5_bc6d_f2823e92609a_00000001.tmp (No such file or directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.getInputStream(DiskFileItem.java:194) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPart.getInputStream(ApplicationPart.java:100) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile.getInputStream(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:251) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.example.models.File.scanFile(File.java:65) ~[classes!/:1.0]
    at com.example.FilesController.add(FilesController.java:56) ~[classes!/:1.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:64) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Это путь, по которому я хочу сохранять файлы загружаемые на сервер.*

На локальной версии всё работает, но проблема возникает на сервере.

Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, ошибка в коде и не понимание как это работает.

В коде я делал с мультипарт файлом .transferTo. Как оказалось, в этот момент Томкат уже не хранит этот файл во временных.

Но почему на локалеке работало, а на сервере нет - загадка.